# transform a string representing a list in each cell of a polars DataFrame column to an actual list

Tags: python, python-polars

I am new to polars library and the title says it all regarding what I am trying to do.

Doing this with the pandas library I would use `apply()` and the build in `eval()` function of Python. since `eval("[1,2,3]")` returns `[1,2,3]`.

This can be done in polars as well - below I have an expected output example - but polars strongly recommends to use its `Expression` API. I searched the [Expr.str](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/string.html) attribute but didn't find an expression that does this. Am I missing something or should go with `apply()`?

```
data = {'col_string': ['[1,2,3]', '[4,5,6]']}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('col_string').map_elements(eval).alias('col_list'))

shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────┬───────────┐
│ col_string ┆ col_list  │
│ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ str        ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1,2,3]    ┆ [1, 2, 3] │
│ [4,5,6]    ┆ [4, 5, 6] │
└────────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: could you add input and expected output please?

Comment: There is no expression to eval Python code. `col_string` is valid JSON in this example - but maybe that's not always the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your string column is valid JSON, you could use [polars.Expr.str.json_decode](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.json_decode.html) as follows.

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("col_string").str.json_decode().alias("col_list")
)
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────┬───────────┐
│ col_string ┆ col_list  │
│ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ str        ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1,2,3]    ┆ [1, 2, 3] │
│ [4,5,6]    ┆ [4, 5, 6] │
└────────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: It works in this case, an it will work in other cases as well, but it is not very evident for someone trying to do this. polars apart, JSON is a way to transform a string that represents a list to an actual list in pure python as well, but in OP I chose `eval()` python built in function because it seem more appropriate. Anyway, my point is that maybe a function in polars `Expr.str` attribute doing this seems more reasonable.

Comment: @exch_cmmnt_memb Can you perhaps explain what you mean by more reasonable? `.json_decode()` is already an `Expr.str` function. How could things be improved?

Comment: Yes you are right, my point is that doing this through JSON is not very intuitive. I personally searched `Expr.str` attribute before posting, came across `.json_decode()` but did not realized that this would do it. Again this is a personal opinion, and it may be just me. I was searching for something similar to python's built in `eval()`, which suggests that it is the function your are searching. From the functionality perspective, I guess `.json_decode()` is complete.